# кнопка удаления на option

Tags: php, javascript, html

Здравствуйте. Можно ли на `<option>` из selectbox'а наложить кнопочку удаления этого `<option>`? и как это сделать?[image: Что-то вроде этого]

что-то вроде этого

Comment: Нет. Нужно делать свой кастомный селект

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, ну как-то может можно налаживать элемент картинки, потом обрабатывать нажатие на элемент?

Comment: Нет, лучше сделать кастомный селект, в интернете их много, тот же `select2`.

Answer (score 2):

Ну вообще можно попробовать такое сделать. Нужно вставить в `<option>` что нибудь (текст "удалить" или картинку), выровнять её, назначить обработчик клика, и по клику удалять этот `<option>`. Но в целом подход не верный, т.к. в данном случае всем заправляет браузер, поэтому не понятно как всё это будет работать и будет ли, не говоря уже о мультибраузерности.